# hazelcast client and server setup

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using the hazelcast v3.2.4 client -> server setup (my application uses the hazelcast client to connect to the server).  The server(from what I gather) will be able to connect to other server nodes via either TCP or multicast/UDP (I am using the hazelcast xml config file for this purpose).  What is the best approach of making sure that my client connects to an alternate server in case the server it is connected to goes down for any reason or becomes unresponsive?  Ideally, I would treat them as two separate cases (one where the process goes down and the other where the process is still alive on the OS but the server does not respond to any requests).  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide additional members in the client configuration. If one of the servers goes down, it will select another member.

PS:
If you have a smart client (default), it will connect to one of the members in its configuration and then continuously be updated with the newest member information.

Comment: it would be great if working xml configs for server and client were mentioned in the docs in one location (or perhaps I just could not find them specially the client one)

Comment: good point. I'll create a github task for it our document team can pick up.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3522